# Mechanism for addition of hydrogen halides in Alkynes

Tags: organic-chemistry

There is a question in my book where one is supposed to add 2 moles of HCl to But-2-yne.
I've attempted this and got 2,3- Chlorobutane instead of 2,2-chlorobutane which is given as the answer.
I'm unable to attach a photo of the same.
My doubt is, after one chlorine has been attached and the triple bond has been changed to double bond, why is the second Chlorine also attached to the same position as the first one.
One explanation, I think -
Since due to inductive effect of first chlorine, there should be delta plus charge near the chlorine attached atom, so H+ from second Hcl molecule goes to the adjacent atom. Therefore,  same C atom has both Chlorine.
But if I think other wise, as in stability of Carbocation and carbanion, adjacent C atoms 2,3 are getting Chlorine.
Please help me clear the doubt

Comment: @Guru I checked out the site and mechanism given but that is exactly what my doubt is, why is it a geminal chlorine. I mean on second addition, why is Carbocation formed on the C having Chlorine. Wouldn't -I effect of Cl cause high instability?

Comment: @Mithoron Yes I've understood the concept now!